# Failed to connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 with user root (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql-workbench

tengo un problema a la hora de crear una nueva conexion en MySQL Workbench, es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ya tengo el servicio de MySQL corriendo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El detalle o lo extraño aqui es que yo tengo otra conexion ya creada a la cual si puedo conectarme y realizar todo lo demás, pero al tratar de crear esta conexión no me deja.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espero que me puedan ayudar a resolver este problema que tengo

Comment: veo 2 MySQL ¿es el mismo servicio?

Comment: Amm no sabría decirte, uno solo dice MySQL y otro MySQL80.

Comment: ¿De casualidad utilizas XAMP?

Comment: Si tengo xampp, pero no lo tengo ejecutando xampp